# Mouseover function and mouseleave function keeps working when resize window

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I want to show a menu when hover over a user. But I want the hover gone when the window size is below 977.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).on("load resize", function(event){
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    var timer;
    if (windowSize >= 977) {   
        $(".crmUser, .userMenu").on("mouseover", function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            openSubmenu();
        }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            timer = setTimeout(
              closeSubmenu
            , 800);
        });

        function openSubmenu() {
            $(".userMenu").addClass("userOpen").fadeIn("fast");
        }
        function closeSubmenu() {
            $(".userMenu").removeClass("userOpen").fadeOut("fast");
        }
    } else { }
    }).trigger("resize");    
});
```

I even made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Teezii/1f1Lnz6r/), but window resizing doesnt work there.
I am not sure what I am missing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
$(document).width();
```

Instead of :

```
$(window).width();
```

And use the condition `$(document).width()>=977` inside event's callback (mousehover) :

```
   $(".crmUser, .userMenu").on("mouseover", function() {
        if($(document).width()>=977){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            openSubmenu();
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

this well worked for me

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var oreientedWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
 if(oreientedWidth < 767){
   //use your code here
 }
});
```